# image_tag with image in /tmp folder in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I am playing with Rails and I know I should store my images to AmazonS3. However, for development purposes, I want to store some of my images in /tmp, and then see how they look in a view.

Is it possible to access `/tmp` folder from the view?

I have tried `<%= image_tag '/tmp/mypic.png' %>` and is not showing up. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: How do you upload images to your site?

Comment: All this is done locally. I am actually generating the images with ChunkyPNG

Comment: You probably want to create a directory under `RAILS_ROOT/public`, e.g. `public/tmp` and then use `image_tag` on that.

`/tmp` is under the root system directory and won't be accessible to your web server, for security reasons.